# UIBarbuttonItem is not on right side of tool bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitoolbar

I have code in my view controller in `viewDidLoad` like this. But the `UIBarButtonItem` is not on the right side of the tool bar. It is in left side. How to give title to toolbar also?

```
UIToolbar *toolbar = [UIToolbar new];
toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;

// create a bordered style button with custom title
UIBarButtonItem *playItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Play" 
            style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered  
            target:self
            action:@selector(flipToSchedules:)] autorelease];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = playItem;
NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: playItem,  nil];
toolbar.items = items;

// size up the toolbar and set its frame
// please not that it will work only for views without Navigation toolbars. 
[toolbar sizeToFit];
CGFloat toolbarHeight = [toolbar frame].size.height;
CGRect mainViewBounds = self.view.bounds;

[toolbar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 
             CGRectGetWidth(mainViewBounds), toolbarHeight)];
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];
```

Answer (score 7):

Assigning the `playItem` as the `rightBarButtonItem` of `self.navigationItem` does not make sense, since that will set the button as a button of the navigation bar at the top, and you want to place it in the toolbar (at the bottom)

To solve this, you'll have to create another button with a flexible width and add that as the first item of the toolbar:

```
UIBarButtonItem *flexible = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
toolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexible, playItem, nil];
[flexible release];
```

Comment: A flexible-width button item is definitely the way to go, here.